# multiple string comarisons using or in a xslt if condition

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I want to remove certain tags from my input xml and convert into to the desired output xml using XSLT.
This is my XSLT

```
<xsl:param name="ID"/> 
 <xsl:template match="/">

     <Table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Apo/*">
         <xsl:variable name="target" select="name(.)" ></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="not($target = 'ApoID') or not($target = 'Instructions') or not($target = 'RouteSwitch')">                   
     <Row>        
        <ApoID>
          <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
        </ApoID>
        <AttributeName>
          <xsl:value-of select="$target"/>
        </AttributeName>
        <AttributeValue>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </AttributeValue>
      </Row>
       </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Table>

  </xsl:template>
```

When i use this it's not filtering. But when use only one condition it's getting filtered out. The following removes ApoID tag from my input XML and gives the expected result.

```
 <xsl:param name="ID"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">

     <Table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Apo/*">
         <xsl:variable name="target" select="name(.)" ></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="not($target = 'ApoID') ">                   
     <Row>        
        <ApoID>
          <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
        </ApoID>
        <AttributeName>
          <xsl:value-of select="$target"/>
        </AttributeName>
        <AttributeValue>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </AttributeValue>
      </Row>
       </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Table>

  </xsl:template>
```

Please help me to use the multiple string comparisons in the XSLT if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test

```
not($target = 'ApoID') or not($target = 'Instructions') or not($target = 'RouteSwitch')
```

will succeed for every value of `$target`, because if the value is `ApoID` then it isn't `Instructions` and vice-versa.  To test if the value is *none* of those possiblities you either want to use `and` instead of `or` or bracket it differently

```
not($target = 'ApoID' or $target = 'Instructions' or $target = 'RouteSwitch')
```